# Tibble with Date column is not identical to itself after writing and reading with feather

Tags: r, feather

Let's consider the tibble

```
x <- tibble::tibble(start_date = lubridate::ymd(NA, NA, "2016-01-01", "2018-04-01", NA))
```

Obviously it is identical to itself

```
testthat::expect_identical(x, x)
```

But if i write the file to disk and then I read it then I get an error

```
library(feather)
write_feather(x, "x.feather")
x_feather <- read_feather("x.feather")
system("rm x.feather")
testthat::expect_identical(x, x_feather)

# Error: `x` not identical to `x_feather`.
# Rows in x but not y: 1. Rows in y but not x: 1.
```

Comment: Seems more like an issue for the **feather** package than a question?